# html geo location not working across all browsers

Tags: html, mobile, safari, geolocation

I'm using the html5 JS function `navigator.geolocation`

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoLocationSuccess, geoLocationError);
}
```

When I run the function on windows 7 in chrome, ff, ie10, it returns almost instantly with my location.

Now I'm testing on a new ipad with mobile safari.  The iPad initially prompts if I want to allow the browser to use my location.  I click yes.  After about a minute the geolocationError function is called with error code 2 (location is unavailable).

Both devices are on the same wifi network and one can find the location and the other can't.

I've read mobile safari supports the geolocation function.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in iOS 6 according to this Apple Support thread; [geolocation doesn't work with iOS 6 web apps!](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4313850?start=60&tstart=0)